# How is the pythonic way to create a reference to a own python class instance and use it?

Tags: python, reference, pass-by-reference

I would like to store the instance of a class in a container like a list. Other classes/methods should access this instance.

Below is a code snipped which defines a data point.

```
class dataPoint(object):
    def __init__(self, name, typeUUID, value = None):
        self.name = name
        self.typeUUID = typeUUID
        self.value = value
```

I like to define a method which gives me the reference (no copy constructor, etc.) to this object. Maybe like this:

```
def getRef(self):
    return ???
```

These references I like to use in different list. The reference I like to use to set properties/call functions of the data point. Below is some pseudocode:

```
# define a conatiner with datapoints    
myContainer = [dataPoint("temperature","double",273.15), dataPoint("power","double",230), dataPoint("errorcode","uint32",666)]

# define interfaces which refers to the datapoints
interface1 = [ref("temperature"), ref("power")]

interface2 = [ref("errorcode"), ]

interface3 = [ref("temperature"), ref("power"), ref("errorcode")]
# set temperature to 300K
ref("temperature") = 300.0

# interfaces
print (interface1[ref("temperature")]) --> 300K
print (interface3[ref("temperature")]) --> 300K
```

How to do this in Python and how to do this pythonic?

Comment: `myContainer` is the only thing that knows about the specific instances of `dataPoint`; neither any specific instance of `dataPoint` or the class itself tracks information about other instances.

Comment: Put another way, `getRef` would be a method of *another* class that can track groups of related `dataPoint` instances. (As Tom Dalton shows in his answer, `DataPoint` can be instrumented to act as the instance tracker.)

Comment: Is this the common way to solve that kind of problems or is this only a particular solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the "instance-container" in the class itself:

```
class DataPoint:
    instances = {}

    def __init__(self, name, typeUUID, value=None):
        self.name = name
        self.typeUUID = typeUUID
        self.value = value

        self.instances[name] = self

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, name):
        return cls.instances[name]
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
>>> d1 = DataPoint("foo", "12345")
>>> d2 = DataPoint("bar", "67890")

>>> DataPoint.get("foo")
<DataPoint object at 0x.........>
```

Comment: In you approach 'DataPoint' holds all instances of it and managing them. Looks like a solution. What is with a more C/C++ concept of passing (smart) pointers through the system?

Comment: All python objects are 'smart pointers' e.g. all variables are references.